# User authentication using magento api

Tags: php, api, magento

I am using this code to authenticate user on magento is

```
$redirecturi = 'http://localhost/magento';
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://localhost/magento/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=".$redirecturi;
$customerAuthorizationUrl = 'http://localhost/magento/oauth/authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://localhost/magento/oauth/token';

$oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
$oauthClient->enableDebug();

$requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
header('Location: '.$customerAuthorizationUrl.'?oauth_token='.$requestToken['oauth_token']);
exit(0);
```

but it display fatal error like this 'Class 'OAuth' not found'. I use this link for authentication [magento authentication](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html).
Please review this and reply answer.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have OAUth Extension for PHP installed. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.installation.php

Comment: please help me to install oauth extension and give me library file to add.

Comment: The library file you need depends on your PHP Version and Server OS. All you need is described on the link I've posted above.